# install4j: Installation folder available for all users without elevated launcher

Tags: install4j

We have the following requirements for our install4j-generated installer on Windows:

- "install for all users" option should be supported
- installation folder should be writable for all the users without administrative rights

We consider placing installation folder under "Program Files" or "%PROGRAMDATA%" by default.
Seems like in any case we need to use "Add windows file rights" action to make installation folder writable for all users.

Do you think it should work or are there better alternatives to meet our requirements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Windows, there is no folder that is writable for all users by default. So using the "Add windows file rights" action is the only possibility.

Comment: One more question: could you please advice which folder better suits our needs: "Program Files" or "%PROGRAMDATA%"?

Comment: If it's the entire installation, I would use Program Files.